# How to enter "+" as a value in excel

Tags: excel

I need to enter the following text in a cell:

```
+A
```

It is important that it be without quotes. The problem is that it is reading it as a formula and automatically turning it into `=+A` and reading it as a formula. I do not want to enter this as a formula as it will give me the result `#NAME?` result. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: better for superuser than stackoverflow

Comment: why the downvote? I searched the internet for this answer but couldn't find anything. Maybe I was entering in the wrong search terms but I tried "how to enter = as value in excel" and "how to enter + as value in excel", and found nothing.

Comment: such bs that little things like not using correct formatting or posting on the wrong site are preventing me from getting over 50 reputation even after I fix my mistakes.

Comment: Reputation is a measure of your experience on the site, and knowing which questions are right for the site is a core component of this. I see your point that there is no easy way to know this without first receiving the negative reinforcement (downvote) that is frustrating you, but you should know that a downvote is not a personal attack. Please review the information in the "closed as off-topic" box and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and stick around to help make SO better for all of us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add a single quote before:

```
'+A
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply add a single quote before the sign:

```
'+A
```

This will appear as `+A`

Or you could do something like:

```
="+A"
```

---

Another option yet would be to first format the cell as text and then you can input anything without excel wanting to treat it as formula.